# How to pass current index to fancybox iframe

Tags: iframe, fancybox

I have a group of links that I call fancybox on with the arrows enabled so that the user can click next and prev. Each link is decorated with the iframe class and href='/editdata.aspx'. I would to remove the arrows and pass in the current index so that the editdata.aspx save button can say "save and next" until it reaches the last link, which will then say "save and close".

From editdata.aspx I use

```
var numLinks = $(".link-items", parent.document.body).children("a.iframe").size();
```

This gives me the total number of links. I just need to know the current link that is being displayed to the user so that I can update the save button text.

Here is a sample of my code in editdata.aspx:

```
// change the save button to save and next if fancybox is loading multiple links
        if (parent.$.fancybox) {
            var links = $(".links", parent.document.body);
            if (links && links.length > 0) {
                var numlinks  = $(links).children("a.popup").size();
                var index = getParameterByName('index');
                if (index == numlinks ) {
                    // this element is the last item to display so change the "save and next" to "save and close"
                    $("#btnSave").val("Save & Close");
                    $("#btnSave").click(function () {
                        parent.$.fancybox.close();
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $("#btnSave").val("Save & Next");
                    $("#btnSave").click(function () {
                        parent.$.fancybox.next();
                    });
                }
            }                
        }

function getParameterByName(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
        var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
        var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
        var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
        if (results == null)
            return "";
        else
            return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats easy for v2 -

```
jQuery(".fancybox").fancybox({
    beforeLoad : function() {
        this.href = this.href + '?index=' + this.index;
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. The value for this.index is always the same number. All the href's have the same index value.

Comment: I updated my question to include the jquery I am using in my iframe page.

Comment: That is definitely working for me. btw, you can get index within iframe like - parent.$.fancybox.current.index

Comment: (or use parent.$.fancybox.coming.index if you are preloading the iframe)

Comment: Yes you are correct. There is something else in my code that is causing issues. When I create a simple test page the index is loading correctly.